# Creating Multiple Input on React

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, responsive, multiple-input

[Home Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFDbh.png)

[Data-Form Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxKnb.png)

[useInput Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29TQQ.png)

[Table Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGpKB.png)
[Output of Code (I can't add 3. row)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxy4a.png)

I would like to get input and put it table as table data. But ı can add only one triple data I cant add a second row. The second question is I would like to reset input boxes when I submit the form how could I do it.third question is how could ı make empty table at the beginning(I could not describe empty object). I dont need to save it on Json or any database ı just wanted to add when I open website. I mean it will be temporary data.
Thank you for Helping :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputData = []  //Global

const DataFormComponent = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({data1: "", data2: "", data3:""})
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         setFormData({...formData, data1, data2, data3})  //spread operator and also duplicate properties in object gets assigned the new value         
         inputData.push(formData);
         console.log(inputData);
         setFormData({data1: "", data2: "", data3: ""}
  }

  return(
     <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
        <input name = "data1" type = "txt"/>
        <input name = "data2" type = "txt"/>
        <input name = "data3" type = "txt"/>
        <button type = "submit">SUBMIT FORM</button>
      </form>
    )
  }

export default DataFormComponent
```

Comment: I mean I get 3 input from my form and these 3 input directly going my table but if ı want add another inputs its not getting

Comment: You didn't find my solution helpful to your last 2 questions?

Comment: İts very useful sorry i didnt mention about it  thank you :)

Comment: No problem buddy, I wish to help you further until you accept my answer.

Comment: You're not storing your inputs. Do this- Create an empty array and push the input values into this array and then you can console.log array values, Okay :)